# Spring boot in docker does not seem to use application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile

I am running into issues with running my spring boot application from within a docker container. When i run my jar packaged with `mvn package` locally it works normally and the app picks up the configuration in application.properties.

The problem occurs when trying to run the jar in a docker container. When running it in a docker container it seems that the values in application.properties(data source etc) are no longer used when running, which makes them go back to default.

I can tell this by the fact that spring tries to set the data source to localhost:5432, which is not what i have set in application.properties.

This is the application.properties i am using. For what is worth, Intellij Community indicates that the properties are unused. This file is located in src/main/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

org.app.jwtSecret= secret
org.app.jwtExpirationMs=86400000

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:127.255.255.255:5432/database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I am using the following pom.xml. The `<build><plugin><execution>` tag was added so that application.properties is read properly in the jar, without this application.properties does not work when using `mvn package`. `mvn spring-boot:run` however does work without the execution tag. I have already tried using a `<resources>` tag in my `<build>` and it does not fix my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.2.1</version>
                <configuration combine.self="append">
                    <includeTests>false</includeTests>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>High</threshold>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the dockerfile I am using. I have tried manually passing application.properties but it does not seem to work for me. `"-Dspring.config.location=file:/application.properties"` does not seem to affect anything or fix my problem. Using `"--spring.config.location=file:/application.properties"` instead is an unresolved argument and does not do anything either. Removing the manual `spring.config.location` also does not do anything.

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DB_USERNAME
ARG DB_PASSWORD
ARG DB_URL
ENV DB_URL=$DB_URL
ENV DB_USERNAME=$DB_USERNAME
ENV DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
ADD /target/*.jar app.jar
ADD /src/main/resources/application.properties /application.properties
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.config.location=file:/application.properties", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

This is the start of the build log for running the application inside the docker container. You can see that spring is trying to connect to localhost:5432 which is not what has been set in application.properties

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.7)

2023-10-02 18:01:47.269  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.org.project.projectApplication    : Starting projectApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.8.1 on 681bd9eb3734 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2023-10-02 18:01:47.273 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.org.project.projectApplication    : Running with Spring Boot v2.6.7, Spring v5.3.19
2023-10-02 18:01:47.275  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.org.project.projectApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-02 18:01:48.585  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-02 18:01:48.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 119 ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-02 18:01:49.903  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-02 18:01:49.920  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-02 18:01:49.921  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.62]
2023-10-02 18:01:50.024  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-02 18:01:50.025  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2675 ms
2023-10-02 18:01:50.131  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-10-02 18:01:50.330  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-10-02 18:01:50.426  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.8.Final
2023-10-02 18:01:50.716  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-10-02 18:01:50.874  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-02 18:01:51.935 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:301) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar!/:42.3.1]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1243) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:121) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:155) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1826) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
```

For extra information. This project runs fine locally. Getting it to work in a jar took quite a bit of work and running the jar inside of docker has not worked at all for me. I would really appreciate any insights!

Comment: Did you tried just remove 
ADD /src/main/resources/application.properties /application.properties
and run:
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

properties should be included in jar

Comment: I'm curious why you are manually adding the properties file to the docker container and trying to reference it on the command line?  application.properties will be bundled in your jar automatically.  Also, I do believe it is working just fine.  All addresses in the 127/8 network are loopback addresses, some systems will resolve these to localhost.

Comment: Removing the add for application properties and the argument in entrypoint results in the exact same problem.

Comment: A second thing to add is that I'm a little surprised this works anywhere.  I believe the syntax for your URL isn't correct.  If you specify both a host and a database you'll need to it needs to follow this pattern, `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database`. You're missing the `//`

Comment: If you have correct properties in file try:
FROM xxxx
ADD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
and should work fine

Comment: @lane.maxwell The manual application.properties was a failed attempt to get it to work. Removing it doesnt affect anything. When running the jar not in docker through the command line, it reads the set data source correctly, but in docker its always localhost. No matter what address i put as datasource, it will always use localhost:5432 in docker, which is exactly my problem.

Comment: @TimMisiewicz see my follow-up comment.  I'm not sure if this is the culprit, but the syntax of the URL is not correct.  This could be causing it to default to localhost, just a hunch.

Comment: @lane.maxwell After reviewing, it seems youre hunch is in fact correct. It seems that postgres data source URLs without the // work on windows (which is what my dev machine is running on) but dont work on linux. Youre a livesaver mate, thanks!

Comment: @TimMisiewicz Glad that worked for you.  I hate bugs like this, almost impossible to find the cause.